# How to show $\frac{M_1 \oplus M´}{M_1} \simeq \frac{N_1 \oplus N´}{N_1} $ if we know $M´ \simeq N´$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory

> > Krull-Schmidt decomposition theorem states that for $R$-algebra $A$ and $M, N, M´$ and $ N´$ right $A$-modules such that $M = M_1 \oplus \ldots M_r $ and $N = N_1 \oplus \ldots N_s $, where $End_A(M_i)$ and $End_A(N_i)$ are local algebra (meaning that have unique maximal right ideal or have only 0 and 1 as its idempotents) for all $i,j$. If $M \simeq N, `$ then $r)s$ and there is a permutation $\sigma$ such that $M_i \simeq N_{\sigma(i)}.$

In the proof of this theorem by induction on $r$, in the final step we need to prove for $R$-algebra $A$ and $M, N, M´$ and $ N´$ right $A$-modules such that $M = M_1 \oplus M´$ and $N = N_1 \oplus N´$.

How can we prove that if $M´ \simeq N´$ by induction steps then $M_1 \oplus M´ \simeq  N_1 \oplus N´$?

Or how to show $\frac{M_1 \oplus M´}{M_1} \simeq \frac{N_1 \oplus N´}{N_1} $ if we know $M´ \simeq N´$?

How can we use projections $\pi_1 : M_1 \oplus M´ \to M_1$ and $\bar{\pi}_1 : M_1 \oplus M´ \to N_1$ and $\pi´ : M_1 \oplus M´ \to M´$  and $\bar{\pi}´ : M_1 \oplus M´ \to N´$  and injections $\iota_1: M_1  \to M_1 \oplus M´ $ and $\bar{\iota}_1 : N_1  \to M_1 \oplus M´$ and $\iota´: M´  \to M_1 \oplus M´ $ and $\bar{\iota}´ : N´  \to M_1 \oplus M´$ for to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: You are missing some hypothesis. The claim in your second paragraph is not true under the conditions you listed in the first paragraph.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Many thanks! I edited. Can you please take a look at it?

Comment: Again, the claim does not follow from the hypotheses you list. Probably during the proof some properties of the modules are proved that are needed to reach the conclusion you want. At the very least you could tell us where you are reading this proof.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Many thanks! can you please let me know what other hypotheses do we need for to be able to show the second (and the third paragraph)?

Answer (score 1):

When you say $(M_1 \oplus M')/M_1$, you have to be careful here, because $M_1$ is not literally a submodule of $M_1 \oplus M'$.  Really, you are identifying $M_1$ as a submodule of $M_1 \oplus M'$ via $x \mapsto (x,0)$.

Projection onto the second component $M_1 \oplus M' \rightarrow M'$ is a surjective homomorphism with kernel $M_1$.  The first isomorphism theorem induces an isomorphism $M' \cong (M_1 \oplus M')/M_1$.  Similarly, $N' \cong (N_1 \oplus N')/N_1$.  So assuming $M' \cong N'$, you get

$$(M_1 \oplus M')/M_1 \cong M' \cong N' \cong (N_1 \oplus N')/N_1$$

Comment: Many thanks for your answer!

Comment: You're welcome.  If you're satisfied with the answer, you can "accept" it by clicking the check mark.

Comment: The direct sum of modules is the coproduct in the category of modules. It comes with *canonical* maps from the two summands to the direct sum. In particular, $M_1$ is literally a submodule of $M_1\oplus M'$ in a canonical way.